# NullPointerException because of overwritten function and call by superclass

Tags: java

Following setup:

```
public class Superclass
{
    private String params;

    public Superclass(String params)
    {
        this.params = params;
        doStuff();
    }

    public void doStuff()
    {
        // uninteresting stuff
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass
{
    private Object someObject;

    public Subclass(String params, Object someObject)
    {
        super(params);
        this.someObject = someObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void doStuff()
    {
        someObject.toString(); // <- causes NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Superclass creates an User Interface while Subclass should create a more specialized version.

From a software engineering point of view, what would be the cleanest way to prevent the `NullPointerException` while "Subclass" still extends "Superclass"?

Comment: A clean way would be to either: 1) Push Object someObject up to SuperClass – **only if it makes sense**, initialise it there and then work on it, or 2) Not call `doStuff()` from your super class constructor. Let the object get created first before performing any action.

Answer (score 2):

The parent class has *no* apparent reason at construction time to call `doStuff`.

Simply put, don't put the call there.   These classes should be constructed independently of each other.  The parent class should not have a dependency on any data from the child to complete its construction; any methods that are overridden by the child that are called in the parent's constructor will introduce this dependency.

If you *do* find you need to invoke an extra method in the parent, though, you could make a `final` method and no ill effect would happen, since the child wouldn't have access to that method.

```
public class Superclass {
    private String params;

    public Superclass(String params) {
        this.params = params;
        doStuffParent();
    }

    public final void doStuffParent() {
        // uninteresting stuff
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        // uninteresting stuff...again?
    }
}
```

Comment: why not final private ?

Comment: Depends on if you want to invoke the method from an instance of the `Superclass` or not.  That's a design decision more than anything else.

Comment: cuz I am reading a book and the book advice to use final private all the time in order to prevent any change at runtime ?

Comment: can you explain "Simply put, don't put the call there. These classes should be constructed independently of each other." so I can vote u up?

Comment: To play Devil's Advocate, does the book mention anything about reflection?  ;)  That aside, again it's up to the OP/implementer to adjust its visibility.

Comment: oh wowwwwwwww how did you know? I am speechless. ya it did but when I used the sample the filed could not be changed at the runtime at all make me confuse why? since the book says it would be change the value of a filed

Comment: how parent can be dependent on child class?

Answer (score 0):

From a software engineering perspective, you are trying to perform an action on an object that has not yet been constructed. Map this idea to your real class and its job, you'll understand that there's some problem with the super class constructor because its trying to work on an object in a bad state.

That being said, you have a few options.

- If it makes sense, try to pass `Object someObject` to the super class. May be the super class really needs it for it to work.
- Do not call `doStuff()` within the super class constructor. It probably even makes sense to call it explicitly outside of both constructors.
- Let your extended class's constructor call `doStuff(..)`.

Comment: can you please "Do not call doStuff() within the super class constructor. It probably even makes sense to call it explicitly outside of both constructors." explain this in depth plz?